# Simplification of the topology of a mesh object

Tags: mesh, modifiers

Is there a way in Blender to simplify a mesh which consists of multiple triangles without removing triangles? The structure should remain the same, only a few larger ones should emerge from the many individual triangles. 
This simplified object should be used for level of detail views and from the distance only the structure should be recognizable, but no elements may be missing, as e.g. it is with the Decimate modifier is the case. Here, triangles are simply removed, which from a distance then looks like there is no element at all. Especially with an object that represents a land surface, elements are missing on the edge.
Is there any other way with Blender to create such an object?

Comment: Can you add a screenshots?

Comment: added two screesnhots of the scene

Comment: I think, you can replace it by 5-10 faces with alpha texture

Comment: But the mesh has no texture, just a material assigned with a color. Currently, it exists of around 22.000 Faces. I need to do this for a lot of other mesh objects, this is only one of it.

Comment: well, 22000 faces it's a lot for game engines with so small amount of details, I think you need to replace some geometry with textures. If there is a lot of objects, you can use scripting for automate your work.

Comment: yeah, the object is imported form a Shapefile and represents a landsurface. Then its exported as glTF to view it in Cesium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. The problem was that BlenderGIS imports the shapefile incorrectly and I first have to remove several vertices (with `bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles (threshold = 0.001`). Then the decimate modifier will work,too.